# How to fix 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values" error in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am working on a Powershell script to automate SharePoint 2016 on-prem Popularity Trend reports. 
For this I'm using the SearchServiceApplication in conjunction with the method 'GetRollupAnalyticsItemData" which works fine to get total hits, unique users etc.

Now I am trying to get hits and users per day and per month. for this I found the methods 'GetHitCountForDay(DateTime)' and 'GetHitCountForMonth(DateTime)'.

It is working fine per month and I get expected output but I receive an error when trying to use the 'GetHitCountForDay' method. The error is:

```
Exception calling "GetHitCountForDay" with "1" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. 
Parameter name: date"
At C:\Users\****\Desktop\Untitled4.ps1:11 char:1
+ $result.GetHitCountForDay($FilterDate)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

I tried to change the DateTime to only Date but that gives a different error entirely.

Expected output would be an integer number of the hits for that particular day (like it is with the month method where no errors are coming and I get an integer number of the monthly hits).

My Code:

```
searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$site = Get-SPSite http://sitecollection

$result = $searchApp.GetRollupAnalyticsItemData(1,[System.Guid]::Empty,$Site.ID,[System.Guid]::Empty)

$FilterDate = Get-Date "2018-12-20"
$result.GetHitCountForDay($FilterDate)
$result.GetHitCountForMonth($FilterDate)
```

Do I need to change the filterdate in any way or am I doing something wrong with the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right but data are stored only 14 days by default (which is maximum).

```
$ssp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy
$config = $ssp.GetAnalyticsTenantConfiguration([Guid]::Empty)
$config.EventTypeDefinitions | ? { $_.EventTypeId -eq 1 }
```

Look for `RecentPopularityTimeframe`.

> Reference:
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-recommendations-and-usage-event-types#change-the-recent-time-period-for-a-usage-event-type